# ConTeXt: How does interactionmenu work?

Tags: context, presentations

How does context's interactionmenu work?

I tried it the following way:

```
\setuppapersize[S6]
\setuplayout[
    topspace=0pt,
    height=fit,
    width=fit,
]

\setupinteraction[
    state=start,
    menu=on,
]
\setupinteractionmenu[right][
    state=start,
]
\startinteractionmenu[right]
    \placelist[subject][criterium=all]
\stopinteractionmenu

\starttext
\startsubject[
    title={Slide 1},
]
    Content 1
\stopsubject
\page
\startsubject[
    title={Slide 2},
]
    Content 2
\stopsubject
\stoptext
```

This compiles fine, but the menu isn't there. Is there anything I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a heading which is numbered, so it actually is added to some table of contents.  The chosen `subject` is not counted, that is why I defined a new heading `slide` which inherits from `section` (same level as `subject`) but does not display the number.

Then you also have to adjust the margins, such that the list actually fits in there.  I haven't found out yet, where the list is positioned but is seems that it is in `header`, because I have to set that height to zero for the menu to be at the same height as the slide title.

Oh, and you need `\setupinteraction[menu=on]`.

```
\setuppapersize
  [S6][S6]

\setuplayout
  [header=0pt,
   footer=0pt,
   height=fit,
   margin=0pt,
   width=fit,
   edgedistance=12pt,
   rightedge=96pt]

\definehead
  [slide]
  [section]
  [page=yes,
   number=no]

\setupinteraction
  [state=start,
   menu=on]

\startinteractionmenu[right]
  \placelist
    [slide]
    [criterium=all]
\stopinteractionmenu

\setupinteractionmenu
  [right]
  [state=start]

\starttext

\startslide[title={Slide 1}]
  Content 1
\stopslide

\startslide[title={Slide 2}]
  Content 2
\stopslide

\stoptext
```

[image]